# Resetting Infinite Loop when it has been ran 5 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, variables, reset

I've worked on an infinite loop, including variables, an array & am now looking to include a reset function.

During this script, a 'LoopNumber' variable is used to determine which number within the array will be printed to the contents of 'marqueetext' division.

Because the loop number is given the integer of '1' during the start of the script, the variable 'marqueepicker' will be effected. Hence the script must be reset at 5 loops, rather than 6.

```
<script>
    var StopLoop = false;
    var Loop = null;
    var LoopNumber = 0;
    var MarqueeArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
    var MarqueePicker = 0;

    Loop = function(){
        LoopNumber = LoopNumber + 1;
        MarqueePicker = LoopNumber - 1;

    $(".marqueetext").text(MarqueeArray[MarqueePicker]);
        if(!StopLoop) window.setTimeout(Loop,1000);
        }; 

    Loop();

    </script>
```

For the sake of showcasing aspects of JS, this script needs to contain the included attributes.

Previous workings on the reset function include

```
   if (LoopNumber == 6) {
       LoopNumber = 0    
   };
```

I have been unsuccessful at adding these to the script as the loop continues regardless of positioning and location within. I am aware that the code has not been indented and operators may not be entirely correct, however this script is a test module and therefore details and efficiency will be included after.

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=drimOc2l61

If possible, could you provide any help & guidance on this reset! Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using a while loop http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace the line

```
LoopNumber = LoopNumber + 1;
```

with

```
LoopNumber = LoopNumber % MarqueeArray.length + 1;
```

This will ensure that your loop number is always in the appropriate range for your marquee array

### -DEMO-

Comment: that is extremely useful, I knew it'd be something extremely simple. Thanks for your time sir.

Answer (score 1):

One quick issue with your script...

```
if (LoopNumber == 6) {
    LoopNumber == 0    
};
```

Should be...

```
if (LoopNumber == 6) {
    LoopNumber = 0    
};
```

Don't use double equals to reset the variable.